# Не отправляет POST, возвращая 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: php

Реализована следующая конструкция:

Форма с `action = "/?page=pages&controller=add"` где `page` - имя класса, `controller` - имя метода, которому необходимо передать данные из формы.

```
public function add() {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR!!!";
    }
}
```

Однако при отправке запроса возвращается `ERROR!!!`.
Если смотреть в Firebug, то после отправки формы выполняется сначала

`POST constructor?page=pages&controller=add`

(переданные POST переменные отображаются) со статусом 301 Moved Permanently, а
потом

`GET ?page=pages&controller=add`

который и возвращает ответ `ERROR!!!`.

Почему не удается передать данные?

Форма:

```
<form action="<?php echo BASEPATH;?>?page=pages&controller=add" method = "post"><br/>
    <input name ="title" placeholder ="Наименование"/><br/>
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Описание"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea name="text" placeholder ="Текст"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea name="metakey" placeholder="META-Keywords"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea name="metadescr" placeholder ="META-Description"></textarea><br/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "add" value = "Сохранить"/>
</form>
```

А здесь идет обработка параметров адресной строки:

```
    public function doCommand($uri, $type){
        $controller = '';
        $flag = FALSE;
        $dir = CMPDIR;        
        $f = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($f as $file){
            if(preg_match('/\.(php)/', $file)){
                if($uri === substr($file, 0, -4)){
                    $flag = TRUE;
                    $controller = CMPDIR.$file;                        
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        if($flag === FALSE){
             $error['error'] = 'Страница <b>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.implode('/',$uri).'</b> не существует'; $this->load('error404', $error);
        } else {
            include strtolower($controller);
            $cl = ucfirst($uri);                
            $class = new $cl;
            $md = FALSE;
            $methreg = '';
            $method = get_class_methods ( $class );
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($method); $i ++){
                if (strtolower($method[$i]) === strtolower($type)){                        
                    $md = TRUE;
                    $methreg = $method[$i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($md === TRUE){
                return $class->$methreg();                
            } else { $error['error'] = 'Method не существует'; $this->load('error404', $error); }
        }            
}
```

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей об отправки данных, повешено ли на submit-кнопку какой-нибудь JS-обработчик, хоршо бы привести в вопросе и саму форму. Как происходит обработка данных формы, нет ли в конце этой обработки редиректа, который приводит к GET-запросу на форму?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что массив `$_POST` заполняется только в том случае, если вы передает данные методом POST и строка `page=pages&controller=add` размещена в теле HTTP-запроса. Если вы передаете данные методом GET с GET-параметрами в адресе (т.е. в HTTP-заголовках), то параметры попадают в `$_GET`, массив же `$_POST` остается пустым.

Comment: Каким образом это можно исправить? в админках различных CMS (например, Joomla) данные POST отправляются на страницу с парасетрами

Comment: @M.Sol Нужны подробности, чтобы вычислить, почему у вас возникает второй GET-запрос, из имеющихся данных почти невозможно наверняка сказать даже где он инициируется в JS или в PHP-коде.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась путем добавления слеш перед параметрами в action формы:

```html
<form action="<?php echo BASEPATH;?>/?page=pages&controller=add" method = "post"><br/>
```